# Combination of Service, ProgressBar, Gridview (and his notifydatasetchanged) an QuickAction-Implementation goes wrong

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, quickaction

(Sorry for my mistakes in spelling)

I have a problem in the combination of some things:

I use a GridView to download show content from a database. onClick a file is downloaded which can be viewed later. Its about 20MB. This download is done by a service.

Every item in the gridView contains a progressbar in the layout. this progressbar is just shown if the item is donwloading in the background via the service.

The Service sends a broadcast about the download Progress, the Intent contains the ID of the item to find it in data of the Adapter for the gridview.

A BroadcastReceiver ist registered in my Activity to get the Progress Update (remember, simultaneous downloads are possible) which calls a function "setProgress" in the gridview-adapter

```
public void setProgress(long id, int progress)
{
   for (int i = 0;i < list.size();i++)
   {
      if (list.get(i).getId() == id)
      {
          list.get(i).setProgress(progress);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
   }        
}
```

To this point everything works fine.

Additionally im using QuickAction implementation from http:// www. londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ (Spaces because i cannot post more than two hyperlinks)

Now comes the problem:

Sometimes, i guess when notifydatasetchanged is called and the user taps on an item, the quickaction is shown on a wrong position.

To make this clearer here are two pictures:

The first one is what should happen (in this case a click on the first item of the gridview)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9031500/expected.png

The second picture shows what happens sometimes (only when some downloads are running, thats why i guess its because of the "notifydatasetchanged" and the rebuild of the views). This was also a click on the first item, unfortunately the quick-action is shown to the fourth item:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9031500/wrong.png

This is my implementation in my activity for the call of the quick-action:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    showQuickAction(view, position);
}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    showQuickAction(view, position);
    return true;
}


private void showQuickAction(View view, int position)
{
    RelativeLayout facsimile = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lib_item_image_layout);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Position:"+position);
    currentPaper = TZReader.paperDao.load(libraryAdapter.getItemId(position));
    Log.i(LOGTAG,"Set CurrentPaper:"+currentPaper.getTitelWithDate());

    ActionItem downloadItem = new ActionItem(ACTION_ITEM_DOWNLOAD, "Download", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_download));
    ActionItem readItem = new ActionItem(ACTION_ITEM_READ, "Lesen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_read));
    ActionItem deleteItem = new ActionItem(ACTION_ITEM_DELETE, "Löschen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_delete));
    ActionItem cancelItem = new ActionItem(ACTION_ITEM_CANCEL, "Abbrechen", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_cancel));

    QuickAction mQuickAction = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.HORIZONTAL);

    switch (currentPaper.getState())
    {
    case Paper.DOWNLOADED_READABLE:
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(readItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(deleteItem);         
        break;
    case Paper.DOWNLOADED_BUT_UPDATE:
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(downloadItem);
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(deleteItem);
        break;
    case Paper.IS_DOWNLOADING:
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(cancelItem);
        break;
    case Paper.NOT_DOWNLOADED:
        mQuickAction.addActionItem(downloadItem);
        break;  
    }


    //Set listener for action item clicked
    mQuickAction.setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(QuickAction source, int pos, int actionId) {                        
            //here we can filter which action item was clicked with pos or actionId parameter
            switch(actionId)
            {
            case ACTION_ITEM_DOWNLOAD:
                Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadService.class);
                downloadIntent.putExtra(DownloadService.PARAMETER_PAPER_DB_ID_LONG, currentPaper.getId());
                startService(downloadIntent);
                break;
            case ACTION_ITEM_READ:

                break;
            case ACTION_ITEM_DELETE:
                DeleteAlertDialogFragment newFragment = DeleteAlertDialogFragment.newInstance(currentPaper.getId());
                newFragment.setStyle(SherlockDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,0);
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
                break;
            case ACTION_ITEM_CANCEL:
                break;                  
            }
        }
    });     



    mQuickAction.show(facsimile);   
}
```

Maybe someone has any idea or hints for me how i can handle this problem!
Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

The solution is that i implement my own ProgressBar, which contains now a BroadcastListerner and set the progress on each item. So i can change the value without need to call "notifydatasetchanged". perfect for my needs. Im still not sur if this is a good solution, but it works well.

Here is the code for the Progressbar:

```
public class ListeningProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

public ListeningProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


final IntentFilter intentDownloadProgressFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadService.DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS_BROADCAST);
private long paperId = 0;
private boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {

    getContext().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(downloadProgressBroadcastReceiver,intentDownloadProgressFilter);
    isReceiverRegistered = true;

    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if (isReceiverRegistered)
    {
        getContext().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(downloadProgressBroadcastReceiver);
        isReceiverRegistered = false;
    }
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}

private BroadcastReceiver downloadProgressBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadService.PARAMETER_PAPER_DB_ID_LONG, -1);
        int progressValue = intent.getIntExtra(DownloadService.PARAMETER_PAPER_PROGRESS_INT, 0);
        if (paperId == id)
        {
            setProgress(progressValue);
        }
    }
};

public long getPaperId() {
    return paperId;
}

public void setPaperId(long paperId) {
    this.paperId = paperId;
}

}
```

I just use it as a normal custom view in my XML Layout.
In the Adapter i set the id of my content to give the receiver the data just to setprogress if its the right content.

At the end, my problem is solved, the progress is updated without the need to call notifydatasetchanged. Yeah!

Comment: Hello Mate, i have a somewhat similar requirement..Can you please guide as to from where should i broadcast so that i can use it in my customProgressbar class. I am using a service to download data....And i need to show its status just like your requirement..Please help...

Comment: Hello Mate, can you please help me with my above comment?... How do i set the paperID of each progess bar?  having a tough time figuring out...